# % characters unexpectedly added in the middle of filename or folder name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web search form, When i submit my search in the search box,
The result are returned but with contains % in the file name.
for example. the original file name is abc.jpeg, so the result returned will be a%bc.
or if a folder is found with, so its the same for the folder name.
if a folder name is jack, in the result it will be ja%ck.
I have the text box (as a search box, and i have set the value of the search text box as) <%search text%>
Thanks for the help and taking time to read it.
I am using Asp.net, C# and Access DB.

code :

```
iscBuilder.AddSelect("* ");
        iscBuilder.AddFrom("[table1] ");
        iscBuilder.AddWhereClause("( column_name like('%" + pQuery + "%') or column_name like('%" + pQuery + "%') or column_name like('" + pQuery + "%') or column_name like('" + pQuery + "%') )");
        iscBuilder.AddWhereClause("(column_name like( '" + path + "') or column_name like( '" + path + "')) order by column_name");
        OleDbConnection sqlconConnection = (OleDbConnection)DatabaseConnection.Instance.GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand1 = new OleDbCommand(iscBuilder.ToString(), sqlconConnection);
        sqlcmdCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
This is how i call the function:    public XmlDocument GetSearchResults(string pQuery, string path,int from , int to)
    {
        List <T> ts= T.GetF().Getresult(pQuery, path);

        return createXMLThumnails(thmbNails,from , to);

    }
```

Have nice day

Comment: How is the search performed? Can you post the code for the search?

Comment: At first, I thought this is somehow done by HTML encoding, but apparently it is not.

Comment: @oded: I post the sql query, how the search is performed.

Comment: @lordcover: no its uses c# , asp.net

Comment: Ouch, SQL injection *heaven* - seriously, you need to look at parameters. Unrelated to the question, but it might explain why your data suddenly gets destroyed... Let me say that more clearly: your code has SERIOUS security issues...

Comment: Your question title seriously makes no sense.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL - what the SQL server sees? You can use the profiler for that.

Comment: Are you **sure** the original filename is `abc.jpeg` ? Have you checked the length of the string? I wonder if you have some non-printing character in there, or some unicode space marker.

Comment: @ marc Gravell; Can you explain that more how can i refine my search? what security issues?

Comment: @oded: i am using access 2007

Comment: @ marc Gravell: yes i am sure about it and suppose folder name is killer so the result will be like kill%20er.

Comment: @Leppie, Wat you suggest for question ?

Comment: @safi - the only way to get "kill%20er" is for the filename to be "kill er" - I really think there is something here that *isn't in the code you are showing us*. What are the values in the html, for example?

Comment: @safi - re "security issues" - "SQL Injection". For the simplest example, [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is the classic, but this is a *genuine* concern - please don't think it isn't just because xkcd pokes fun at it...

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: I am using XMl and AJAX, the result returend to the LIST, THen list is loaded into XML Document. should i post that xml code or java script code for search as well?

Comment: How can developers still not know that concatenating big strings together is not how you build your SQL statements? It's like bricklayers not knowing that you need to use cement.

Comment: @Mark Rendle: what is your suggestion to create this SQL Statement? is this a flaw in my SQL statement?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: @safi You should put values into parameters, rather than concatenating them into your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a parameterised query or stored procedure to get your data - all this joining strings to make SQL statements is very fiddly and problematic.

Have a look at using [Parameterised Queries](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) or Stored Procedures.